# How can I make it so my <article> elements don't overlap eachother?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to post multiple articles to a website, but after using the code that uses position:absolute to center the articles, the articles are now overlapping each other. I want the articles to stack vertically in sequential order. Right now the articles are completely overlapping, and if I had different text it would probably look really weird. I really need some help on this so I have included the following code.

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Bahnschrift;
}

.list-group {
  text-align: center;
}

#logo {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

#menubar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

a:focus,
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.post-title:focus,
.post-title:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: Bahnschrift;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.link {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* tell the container's children to float left: */

.float-my-children>* {
  float: left;
}

.float-my-children>img {
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: calc(10% - 5px);
}

.float-my-children>div {
  width: 90%;
}


/* this is called a clearfix. it makes sure that the container's children floats are cleared, without using extra markup */

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1/* for IE */
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}


/* end clearfix*/

article {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
 <article>
     <div class="interview-link float-my-children clearfix">
         <a href="#">
             <img width="260" height="170" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
         </a>
         <h2 class="post-title">
             <a class="post-title" href="#"> 25 Questions With Stacey Racks </a>
         </h2>
     </div>
 </article>

 <article>
     <div class="interview-link float-my-children clearfix">
         <a href="#">
             <img width="260" height="170" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
         </a>
         <h2 class="post-title">
             <a class="post-title" href="#"> 25 Questions With Stacey Racks </a>
         </h2>
     </div>
 </article>
```

Any ideas how I can get the articles to stack vertically in sequential order?

Comment: Both absolute positioning and floats are troublesome. I use both only as last resorts, and I've been doing front-end dev for more than a decade.

Comment: Can I introduce you to our savior, [`Flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)?

Someone even made [an example](https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/common-flexbox-patterns/#vertical-stack-centered) that looks like what you're asking for!

Comment: How often is the height of your article stack shorter than the viewport, where vertical centering is even a priority?

Comment: @GammaGames That fixed it for the stacking, but it isn't centering the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a horizontally-centered stack is pretty easy with flexbox:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">foo</div>
  <div class="item">bar</div>
  <div class="item">baz</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Quentin Easy enough fix, though it wasn't a part of the question.

Comment: It was implied.

Comment: Hi. This worked to make them no longer stacked on top of each other, but they are not centered. Any ideas?